# MySQL select parent and grandparent

Tags: mysql

Im trying to select the "parent" and "grandparent" node in a adjecency list but dont have a clue how to build by SELECT query (im beginner mysql programmer).

Im trying to make an order system where each distributor can see how much they earned in one month. i get a order from a customer and that customers distributor gets commission from that order, and that distributors "parent" distributor gets a small commission too.

My tables is like so (just wrote the important columns):

```
Table: order
-----------------------------
order_id | customer_id
-----------------------------
1        |  1007
2        |  1004
3        |  1001
4        |  1005
5        |  1009


Table: customers
------------------------------
customer_id | distributor_id   <-- distributor_id is just like parent_id
------------------------------     (customers can also be distributors)
1001    | 0
1002    | 0
1003    | 0
1004    | 1001
1005    | 1004
1006    | 1002
1007    | 1001
1008    | 1005
1009    | 1004
```

For order_id 5, customer 1009, the (parent) distributor is 1004. The (grandparent) distributor for 1004 is 1001. distributor_id of 0 just means no parent distributor.

What i want to do is on one page show all the orders where 1001 gets commission (the parent and grandparent of the customers). I am stuck at only selecting the parent, when grandparent gets into the mix im swimming in deep water, help! :)

EDIT: I might have solved it with this (dont know if its hacky or not):

```
SELECT c.*, o.*
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN orders o ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
LEFT JOIN customers p ON p.customer_id = c.distributor_id
WHERE c.distributor_id = 1001 OR p.distributor_id = 1001
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is that you need to make several queries, one per level as you follow the parent ids. You stop when you run out of parents.

This design for a hierarchy is logical, obvious and usually not suitable for a relational database. The problem is that you simply can't do one SQL query to get a record and all its parents up to the top. To get one record and its parent, you can do a self-join, to do a third level, you can do a second self-join, but how do you keep going until you run out of parents? You can't. SQL has no mechanism for dynamic joins like that. So the solution for this structure is to make multiple queries. For very small trees, there is not a huge performance penalty.

If you want to redesign your tables so that you *can* do things with single queries, you need to use a structure called [nested sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model).

(Edit: Actually I just discovered an SQL extension called "Common Table Expressions" which are designed for hierarchical data. Unfortunately, MySQL does not support it.)

Comment: How would i write that SELECT statement? I dont need parents all the way to the top, always just 2 levels (parent and grandparent) so it does not have to be dynamic

Comment: Like in pseudo code i just want do: SELECT all orders WHERE parent OR grandparent TO orders.customer_id IS 1001

Comment: If you're always looking just two levels up, then you can find the parent of the customer_id you want, and then the parent of that. Then you can do `SELECT * FROM order WHERE order_id IN (<customer_id>, <parent_id>, <parents_parent_id>)`